Why does these orthogonality conditions guarantee a weak solution?
I am reading a paper about the Yamabe equation and here is the link https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jde.2011.03.008.
In the lemma 3.1 of this paper, the author says "Since the orthogonality conditions (3.4)
hold, we easily check that a solution of problem (3.7) produces a weak solution of (3.2)." and I don't understand. Can someone explain this step in details? Thanks!

I scanned the proof of Lemma 3.1. In my humble opinion, the authors may have worded this statement a little bit poorly toward newcomers. What the authors tried to say is roughly more like:

Since the orthogonality is built in the definition of $H$, imposing (3.7) only in $H$ is enough for a weak solution.

Note that the formula in (3.7) itself is already having the form of weak solution for $\phi$, it is just that the space the test functions residing in is smaller than the whole space in consideration. The reason is that $L(\phi)$ has a nontrivial kernel, which was introduced below (3.1), and $L(\cdot)$ being nonlinear makes the presentation less straightforward.
If $L$ is linear, then the presentation will be much simpler, as one can just say to search for the weak solution to $L\phi = f $, we only have to look the solution in a subspace $H \subset V$, where $H\simeq (\ker L)^{\perp}$, and the orthogonal complement is with respect to whatever inner product defined on the whole space $V$.

More update on a linear example:
For example, if $L=-\Delta$ with homogeneous Neumann BC on a bounded domain $\Omega$, then this orthogonality is nothing but to mod a constant out (imposing the solution to be orthogonal to a constant). In the meantime, for an inhomogeneous problem $-\Delta \phi = h$, $h$ has to satisfy certain "compatibility" condition as well. In the linear case it is $\int_{\Omega} h = 0$. (3.7) is your compatibility condition in the nonlinear case. It should be straightforward to verify given the form of $Z_l$, if $\phi$ solves (3.2) weakly then
$$
0 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi L(Z_l) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} Z_l L(\phi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} Z_l h.
$$
You have to check if $Z_l$ and $Z_l$'s gradient decay to zero at infinity.

I am sorry my question is not clear enough and please let me explain it. If H is the H^1 space then (3.4) is necessary to make (3.7) hold since H contains the kernel of L. However, it seems that the author excludes these functions from the working space according to the definition of H. So is (3.4) still necessary in this situation?

@Jay I updated my answer, (3.4) is necessary.
